# Importar celda que contiene fecha o texto laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy importando datos desde un archivo de `excel` pero me he encontrado con un problema al momento de llamar a una celda, estaba importando la fecha de la siguiente manera:

```
'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha_ultima_calibracion']),
```

Pero cuando estaba ingresando datos me di cuenta que esa celda no solo contenia fechas si no que aveces contenia texto como "Excluido" , cuando intente pasar ese dato ya no me lo permitia con ese codigo, por ahora lo estoy pasando normalmente así :

```
'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$row['fecha_proxima_calibracion'],
```

Pero cuando se encuentra con una fecha me salen tipo `43794`de que manera seria optimo solucionar esa parte para que las fechas se vean como deberian ser con un formato `yyyy-mm-dd` y que tambien me inserte de manera normal los textos

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías poner un condicional. Si el valor es igual a 'Excluido' usar ese, si no, convertirlo a DateTime Object. Puede ser un if/else o un operador ternario

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias, lo hice tal cual como me dijiste. Estaria bien si pongo el codigo como respuesta?

Comment: Sí, claro, ten en cuenta que sólo funcionará si el texto es 'Excluido', también se puede hacer la invers, chequear que sea una fecha válida y usar la fecha, o si no, usar cualquier texto. Creo que esta funcíon [isDateTime](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/Date.html#method_isDateTime) te podría servir también

Comment: Hola, Si vas a responder, como comentas, trata de usar una expresión regular para los formatos de fecha **conformes** y un array de **textos** (no fecha) **admitidos**, de modo que `in_array($entrada, $textos)` decida si es texto esperado y tendrías algo como: `if((preg_match( $regexp, $entrada, $matches)&&($matches[0]==$entrada){ ...}elseif(in_array($entrada, $textos)){...}else{ //reportar error de formato }` para ofrecer una solución general

Comment: Por un lado, no guardaría otra cosa que fechas en una columna de fechas.No lo puedo probar ahora, pero a esa función creo que la podrías usar igual que usas `excelToDateTimeObject`, y te devolverá un booleano  `Date::isDateTime($row['fecha_ultima_calibracion')? //verdadero: es una fecha : //falso: no es fecha;`. Puedes probarlo si te funciona también.  Entrando en el terreno de la suposiciones, ese valor 'excluído' suena como a un booleano `incluído/excluido`, o a una relación con un modelo Estado, con atributo `'nombre'` donde estaría `'Incluido', 'Excluido','Activo', 'Pendiente','etc,` .